# DB Design for Event Dependencies

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a series of events (potentially hundreds) segregated into applications. Each one of these events has a dependency on others (except the first one, of course). I'm looking to map all of these dependencies in a table, but I'm not sure the best way to do so. One event can have multiple predecessors, or multiple successors, or both. There are also cases where A is a prereq for B, B is a prereq for C, but A is also a prereq for D, and C and D are both prereqs for E. (I can't assume that the dependency chain is linear.)

I already have a table with all of the events listed with some other details, and the event names are unique. My first thought was to have a "dependency" table that had an ID (PK) field, 'event' field containing the ID from the events table, and a "dependenton" field that also contained an ID from the events table. Obviously each event could have multiple entries if they are dependent on more than one other event. I believe this follows first normal form, but I'm trying to think if there is another design that would be more efficient or easier to work with.

Thank you.

Comment: You're describing a directed, cyclic graph. To what use will the dependencies be put? Are they just documentation, or will they be heavily read to determine, say, state changes?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a "many:many" relationship.

See my [*tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on writing an optimal many:many table.

I assume you have a `PRIMARY KEY` for the Event table; perhaps the event name?  It should be used in the many:many table.

Comment: I have an auto-incrementing number for the primary key. Since the dependencies themselves are treated as entities in our environment (ie they can be moved, added, removed, etc.) I think not having a surrogate PK isn't a wise choice though. Other than that, it seems similar to what I already had in mind.

Comment: At least get rid of the `id` for the many:many table, itself.

Comment: What's the benefit of getting rid of the ID field? It doesn't have to be used to uniquely identify a dependency, but it can be, and when serializing a request into JSON it makes it much easier.

Comment: (1) The pair of ids is `UNIQUE`, hence viable for being the PK.  (2) The ID takes extra space.  (3) Certain operations are slower because of going through `ID` unnecessarily.  (4) The typical user fails to provide the optimal indexes.